Scalar line integrals in the plane

I understand that $\mathbf{r}=\left[\begin{array}{c} x\\ y \end{array}\right]= \left[\begin{array}{c} \cos{s} \\ \sin{s} \end{array}\right]$, whenever $0\le s \le 2\pi$.
However, I don't understand why $x=\cos⁡{t^2}$, $y=\sin{t^2}$?
May anyone explain this?

You would benefit from phrasing the problem in a more clear manner. What is your problem specifically about that parametrisation that you do not understand?

sorry for my bad english .i understand that =⟨,⟩=⟨cos⁡,sin⁡ ⟩ which is come from ^2+^2.if =cos⁡〖^2 〗, =sin⁡〖^2 〗, then s=t^2.why s=t^2?

maybe you need that $0\leq t^2\leq 2\pi$

yes,  0≤s≤2π and 0≤t^2≤2π ,but why s=t^2?how can i know this formula?

is it because : ()=⟨(), ()⟩  for ≤≤,   As ^2+^2=1,    ()=t^2,y()=t^2,then=cos⁡〖^2 〗, =sin⁡〖^2 〗?

There is no formula to "know". Your textbook gave you that specific example of a weird parametrization on purpose. The goal was to denonstrate to you that the value of integral is independent of any weird paramterization a sketchy man on the street late at night could possibly give you.

There is a bijection from $[0,\sqrt{2\pi}] \to [0,2\pi]$ given by $t \to t^2$. The problem using this bijection for the parameterization. Sometimes you can simplify problems significantly by changing coordinates. So this sort of technique will be useful for motivating those changes later.

The point is that the average temperature depends on how you parametrize the curve, even though the integral itself does not. Average depends on uniform sampling, and if your speed varies, the sampling spots will not be evenly spaces on the circle.
